# jquery replace is not working for single quote

Tags: jquery, jstl, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to strip out the single quote from my options in a select box, but the below doesn't appear to be working:

```
$(function(){
  $("#agencyList").each(function() {
    $("option", $(this)).each(function(){
      var cleanValue = $(this).text();
      cleanValue.replace("'","");
      $(this).text(cleanValue);
    });
  });
});
```

It still has the single quote. The select is built with a JSTL forEach loop. Can anyone see what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to assign the new value by using `cleanValue = cleanValue.replace(...)`. Also, if you want to replace all single quotes, use a global RegEx: `/'/g` (which replaces all occurrences of single quotes):

```
$(function(){
  $("#agencyList").each(function() {
    $("option", this).each(function(){
      var cleanValue = $(this).text();
      cleanValue = cleanValue.replace(/'/g,"");
      $(this).text(cleanValue);
    });
  });
});
```

Another adjustment:

- Replaced `$(this)` with `this`, since it's not necessary to wrap the `this` object in a jQuery object.
- Your code can be optimized even more my merging two selectors:

  ```
  $(function(){
    $("#agencyList option").each(function() {
        var cleanValue = $(this).text();
        cleanValue = cleanValue.replace(/'/g,"");
        $(this).text(cleanValue);
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: I updated my code to that, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Risu Make sure that the elements exist (a parent with `id="agencyList"`, with `<option>` elements as children).

Comment: That works.  It would seem that my choice in multiselect ui is misbehaving and not allowing the removal.